# Why is the specific error "substraction" so common in English?

Tags: errors

It seems very common (particularly among non-native English speakers, but I've seen the *typed* form, though not the spoken form, from native speakers too) for people to type or even say "substraction" when they mean "subtraction".

What causes this error? There must be *some* loose rule that the word "subtract" fails to follow, to cause the -s- to be inserted so commonly. Is it a phonotactics thing?

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this; it's possible that english.SE would be a better place for this. Feel free to move it if so.

Comment: This isn’t limited to English – as jogloran’s answer mentions, most Romance languages have actually codified the form with the s, and I’ve heard s forms used in German, Swedish and other languages where the standard form has no s, too. I would hypothesise it’s primarily due to influence from _ab-_, which is _abs-_ before _t-_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on English Language & Usage.

Comment: @GrahamH. I went back and forth between posting it there and posting it here several times. Feel free to move it.

Comment: I struggled with this one myself (last time yesterday, even though I did select the correct one). If I think about it for a minute, I can see that it must come from subtrahere, subtraxi, but the "subst" group is so common in other words...

Comment: @Hearth Given that the phenomenon is common to many languages, not just English, you could just as well remove the “in English” part of the question and leave it here.

Comment: *Subst* seems rather common in scientific terminology: *substitution, substructure, substrate, substance, substantial...* I wonder, if this mistake is more typical for people with particular background (e.g., sciences/engineers vs. humanities.)

Comment: *There are all sorts of typical mistakes in English (and all languages in fact) depending on what the source language is*. In French and Spanish, subtraction is soustraction and sustracción. It would be a typical mistake. Just like Thank**s** God, for some Spanish speakers in English. This is a language learning question, not linguistics.

Comment: Your point is just your opinion. How do you prove it??

Comment: @RogerV.: Also *substage*, *substellar* and *substation*.

Comment: @RogerV. And not only is 'subst' a common pattern, but the consonant cluster 'str' is quite common, potentially resulting in 'muscle memory' turning 'subtract' into 'substract.'

Comment: Especially among computer programmers, who often need to take *substrings* of text.

Comment: @Lambie What do you mean by that? I am asking a question based on an observation, not presenting any kind of opinion or anything that needs proof.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/is-substract-versus-subtract-a-proper-word and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296738/subtract-or-substract - I can confirm, as a French person, that *subtract* sounds weird to my ears. Even after discovering now that I mispronounced that word for many decades, I can't even convince myself to say it as expected. A quick informal poll around me shows that 100 % of native French when asked *Give me some antonyms of 'ajouter' in English* reply *remove* and *sub**s**tract*.

Comment: woah, 35 years of using English in a professional setting and TIL this... I am French so the *bs* structure is more natural, but still.

Comment: Larousse:   soustraction [sustraksjɔ̃]
nom féminin
mathématiques    **subtraction**
  il ne sait pas encore faire les soustractions    he can't subtract yet //Things sound weird when you don't know them...

Comment: @RogerV: You are close to convincing me that *substraction* is correct and almost everybody is saying it wrong.

Comment: The noun form "substraction" is ***not*** common. I had not seen it until I read this post (the closest is *[substaction](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=substaction)*). But misspelling of [the verb forms](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#subtract) are: *[substract](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=substract)*, *[substracted](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=substracted)*, and *[substracting](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=substracting)*. Where did you sample?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Years of everyday conversation with people at school and later at work, both in person and in emails.

Comment: I'm with @PeterMortensen. I've never heard this mispronunciation before.

Comment: @shoover I mean to ask about all forms of "subtract -> *substract", anyway--I didn't worry about which specific form to mention in the question. The insertion of the s is what I'm asking about, and it didn't occur to me that the suffix could matter.

Comment: @Hearth I mean to say, I've never heard "substract-" regardless of suffix. I've just never heard anyone insert an "s" sound between "sub" and "tract." It's just not done in my part of the world.

Comment: @shoover Don't underestimate our brain's capacity for autocorrection. Your ears may have heard it but the mispronunciation may not have reached your consciousness.

Comment: Substrate influence? ;)

Comment: Another just spotted in some AoE2 patch notes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnLiW.png

Answer (score 16):

The combination *bt* doesn't appear very often in English (often where it appeared in Latin, it's been simplified in English pronunciation, like "subtle"), while *bst* appears in words like "abstract". I would chalk this up to analogy with the relatively common and similar-sounding word "abstraction". (In the comments, jogloran also mentions "distraction".)

Comment: Also _extraction_, _instruction_, _abstrusion_, etc. – in general, there are lots of cases where you have a Latinate prefix and a /tr/ at the beginning of the following root, you get an kind of excrescent /s/ (even though the actual /s/ is only excrescent, other times part of the root or prefix).

Comment: And also _subscription_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The s in instruction is from the verbal stem *struere* (cognate to English strew)  and not excrescent.

Comment: @YellowSky And subscription is from Latin scribere, with an initial s in the simple verb.

Comment: @SirCornflakes There was a word missing in my previous comment: it should have said, “even though the actual /s/ is only excrescent _sometimes_”, alluding precisely to it being part of the root in _struere_ and an inherent part of the prefix in _ex-_.

Comment: The absence of real -bt- in English is indeed striking: debt and doubt are further examples of the treatment of this segment in spoken English. On the other hand, pt is quite common and not problematic at all: reptile, crept, ...

Comment: "bst" is also easier to type on a QWERTY keyboard, since touch typists will use the same finger for b and t.

Comment: @SirCornflakes Can't this be generalized to voiced vs unvoiced consonants? Both f and c/k are common before t, but v and g not so much. I can think of a few compound words for gt, like ragtime, but I guess there might be some of those for bt too.

Comment: @SirCornflakes The reason for the silent bs in *subtle*, *debt* and *doubt* is that they all come from old French words that had no b in either spelling or pronunciation (*soutil*, *dette*, *doute*) and the b was added to the spelling by people who recognised Latin words (*subtilis*, *debitum*, *dubito*). This also occured with the silent p in *receipt* (Old French *receite*, Latin *receptum*), but not with the non-p in *deceit* (Old French *deceite*, Latin *deceptum*). Interestingly, the b was restored in French pronunciation for the modern French *subtil*, but not *doute* or *dette*.

Comment: It's not bt: it's sub and tract. Sub is a prefix in English and very used.

Answer (score 14):

I've noticed this too (particularly in non-native but high-level English speakers), but I'm not sure this question is answerable with firm evidence. Different speakers may make the error for different reasons.

If I had to guess, it could be interference from the words "abstraction", "distraction", but note that Spanish actually has *sustracción*, *sustraer*, etc, and French has *soustraction* /sustʁaksjɔ̃/, which might lead speakers of such languages to analogise to **substraction* in English.

Comment: I don't think this is provable.

Comment: I only started making this mistake after hearing my native Francophone student make it, so there's one anecdotal case!

Comment: This speech error is made by native Korean speaker June Huh [here](https://youtu.be/4445Mbw8pYg?feature=shared&t=508) and native Russian speaker Maxim Kontsevich [here](https://youtu.be/1CXvSRQVoZY?feature=shared&t=568), so I wonder if the Francophone influence hypothesis is correct for these examples. In both cases it may not be an on-the-spot error, but rather a misconception that the usual English word really is "substract".

Comment: @Lambie that's why jogloran wrote "I've noticed" and "If I had to guess".

Comment: @LukeSawczak it is certainly not uncommon to Russians - perhaps it has to do with being used to consonant clusters.

Comment: Native speaker of American English [David Malan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._Malan) (professor at Harvard) saying [*substraction*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGo2vwa2U-I&t=4740s) @ 1h19'05"

Answer (score 12):

Technically, "substraction" is a real word, but it is outdated and considered erroneous in modern English.

However, [it derives from the Late Latin "substractus", meaning "take away" and is an alternative form of "subtrahere"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substraction), [which is what "subtraction" is derived from.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/subtraction)

According to [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substraction), the usage of "substraction" is common amongst non-native English speakers due to the similarity to the French "soustraction" and the Spanish "sustracción", which both derive from the Late Latin "substractus".

[You can also see this related question from English.SE about "substract" vs "subtract".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3640/is-substract-versus-subtract-a-proper-word)

Comment: Indeed, it is Medieval Latin. I was surprised to even find a very rare and obolete verb substrahovat(i) in a Czech dictionary, as a variant of rare and obsolete subtrahovat(i). So this dichotomy also exists even outside of Romance languages (+ English).

Comment: This does not explain why people make the mistake....B English speakers make a lot of other mistakes, too.

Comment: @Lambie I think that it does explain it to an extent because the etymology of each variation of the word conforms to the rules of English and leads to the same concept. So, an English speaker could feasibly learn "substraction", and it would not feel wrong because it still conforms to the rules of the language.

Comment: @NelsonO I have been around (as an interpreter) Portuguese, French and Spanish and I have never ever heard this. Everyone just believes what the want to believe. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that it's likely to be interference from the more common combination *st* combination found in other words.

But is also seems like it's harder to pronounce *bt*. Say it slowly and notice the complicated lip and tongue movements that are required. Then insert the *s* and notice how it smoothes the motion.

Comment: I don’t think ease of articulation really plays much of a part here, to be honest. Consider _obtain_ and _abstain_ which are mainly distinguished by the presence or absence of the /s/ – but I’ve never heard anyone mix those up. And I’ve certainly never heard anyone say _*substerfuge_ or _*substerranean_ (granted, these have a different stress pattern, which may also have an affect).

Comment: Good point, although notice that all those examples have a vowel after /bt/.

Comment: But "bt" isn't pronounced, since the "b" and "t" are in different syllables.

Comment: It's interesting to note that _obtrusive_, the only other word that I could find in which _bt_ occurs at a syllable boundary while followed by a consonant, also seems to trigger /s/ epenthesis frequently enough to warrant [a Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obstrusive#Etymology_1) for _obstrusive_ as a misspelling of _obtrusive_.

Comment: But it's not bt: It's sub-tract

Comment: @Lambie I'm not trying to suggest that it's a single phoneme, just a connected sequence of phonemes. /b-t/

Comment: @Barmar But they are not connected except in writing...So, if you learn how to say the word, you wouldn't learn the mistake.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a linguist but I have (unscientifically) noticed as a native American English speaker that many people mispronounce words.

Some words are graced with this more often, with the mispronunciation sometimes even making it into an official source like a dictionary.

Sometimes letters are added, sometimes they're rearranged and sometimes they're removed. The *s*-sound and letter `s` seem to be frequent problems, such as with *ask* (as *axe*), *espresso* (as *expresso*), and even the recent persistent mis-pluralization of words like *mom* (as *moms*).

Consider that through the course of a primary education, most native American English speakers are introduced to subtraction (or *substraction,* as you point out) because it is a core concept in elementary mathematics. They may have cause to use the word often but some combination of society misleading them, difficulty saying certain letter combinations, underdeveloped speaking ability, various speech pathologies, and laziness may cause them to say it incorrectly. Once learned, it may never be corrected.

Comment: _Ax_ is a simple case of **metathesis**. The /ks/ variant is generally considered dialectally marked now, but it was just as normal and correct as the /sk/ variant for many centuries – Chaucer and the Tyndale Bible used it, for example. It may have arisen as a mispronunciation, but you can’t classify it as one now, unless you also want to call _third_ and _bird_ ‘mispronunciations’ of _thrid_ and _brid_. _Expresso_ is a case of **analogy** (_ex-_ is an existing prefix, _es-_ isn’t). And there is absolutely nothing wrong with pluralising _mom_ as _moms_. What else would it be?

Comment: Aside from the tenuous connection to the question, "even the recent persistent mis-pluralization of words like mom (as moms)." — is... "moms" actually a mis-pluralisation?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Although it's off topic, I believe Stephan Samuel is referring to the use of -s as a hypocoristic suffix, in the specific case of "moms" referring to a single person, as used by black Americans. For example, Christopher Wallace, the Notorious B.I.G., [says](https://youtu.be/Uz5o4EjCNLg?feature=shared&t=66) "I got P-A-I-D, that's why my *moms* hate me. *She* was forced to kick me out" (my emphasis). I think "pops" is a better known example of the suffix, and in England we have the terms of address (for one person) "ducks" and "babes", so it's not exclusive to black Americans.

Comment: *"espresso"* / *"expresso"* is [covered by "Weird Al" Yankovic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc&t=1m39s) (at 1 min 39 secs).